# Expose windows vagrant by ngrok

Tags: laravel, homestead, ngrok

Hi I'm using windows vagrant and homestead developing laravel application.

i have this in my hosts file

```
192.168.10.10  laravel.dev
```

I wanted to expose this url so that I can test one requirements like responsiveness and the like.  How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the share command: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#sharing-your-environment

Also, you should change your `.dev` TLD to `.test` otherwise browsers will start complaining about your site.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are you using a private network in your Vagrantfile ? something like :

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.10"
```

Comment: Where to put this line?

Comment: In your Vagrantfile :)